# Spring boot crudrepository memory usage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring's `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` maven dependency to auto-generate our repositories and have done no additional tweaking - my repositories for now all look like:

```
public interface AssetTripRepository extends CrudRepository<Asset, String> {
```

}

In the calling class I inject the repository as follows:

```
@Autowired
public CacheService(final AssetTripRepository assetTripRepository) {
    this.assetTripRepository = assetTripRepository;
}
```

And then use it:

```
for (final Asset asset : assets) {
    final ArrayList<AssetTrips> assetTrips = //call to service
    assetTripRepository.save(assetTrips);
}
```

This all works and persists to the db but the repository doesn't seem to release the objects (assetTrips) even after they've been saved which eventually results in an out of memory exception.

I've used the VisualVM memory sampler and can verify that all assetTrip objects are always on the heap and never get garbage collected, commenting out the save call on assetTripRepository fixes the issue and all assetTrips are garbage collected so it can only be the repository holding on to those references for some reason.

I would expect the assetTrips persisted to be de-referenced and eligible for garbage collection after every iteration of the loop through assets but that's not happening.

Comment: try removing `final` from `assetTrips`.

Comment: Same thing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`- out of interest what was the reasoning for trying without the final? Do the generated repositories de-reference by setting the persisted object to null?

Comment: Is your repository @Transactional?

Comment: @DelPedro no, but the method with the loop that calls assetTripRepository.save(...) is `@transactional`. I have tried removing it there and adding `@transactional` to the repository and get the same thing.